# How do you call a ContentView function from a View object?

Tags: swift, xcode, view, swiftui

I have a demo built to illustrate my question, you can check it out below. I want this SwipeBar to change the background color of the main ContentView but I don't know how to do this. I've used ObservableObject before to accomplish something similar but View's cannot be of type ObservableObject so I'm unsure of how to have this SwipeBar "communicate" with the ContentView that created it. Any ways of doing this?

Quick preview of what this code does: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXqj1.jpg

The entire ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var backGroundColor: Color = .purple

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()

            SwipeBar()

            Spacer()
        }.background(backGroundColor)
    }

    func changeBackgroundColor(color: Color) {
        self.backGroundColor = color
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The entire SwipeBar.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwipeBar: View {

    @State var draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State var greenOpacityLevel: Double = 0.3
    @State var redOpacityLevel: Double = 0.3

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
                            .fill(Color.green)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 70)
                        Text("GREEN")
                            .padding(10)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                    }.padding(.leading, 20)
                     .opacity(self.greenOpacityLevel)

                    Spacer()

                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
                            .fill(Color.red)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 70)
                        Text("RED")
                            .padding(10)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                    }.padding(.trailing, 20)
                     .opacity(self.redOpacityLevel)
                }

                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 375, height: 70)
                    Text("SWIPE LEFT OR RIGHT")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                }
                .offset(x: self.draggedOffset.width)
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20, coordinateSpace: .local)
                .onChanged { value in
                    self.draggedOffset = value.translation

                    if self.draggedOffset.width >= 120 {
                        self.greenOpacityLevel = 1.0
                        self.draggedOffset.width = 120
                    } else {
                        self.greenOpacityLevel = 0.4
                    }

                    if self.draggedOffset.width <= -120 {
                        self.redOpacityLevel = 1.0
                        self.draggedOffset.width = -120
                    } else {
                        self.redOpacityLevel = 0.4
                    }
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    if self.draggedOffset.width <= -120 {
                        // Call the ContentView's changeBackGround function and pass in Color.red
                        print("background should change to red")
                    }
                    if self.draggedOffset.width >= 120 {
                        // Call the ContentView's changeBackGround function and pass in Color.green
                        print("background should change to green")
                    }
                    self.draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
                    self.redOpacityLevel = 0.4
                    self.greenOpacityLevel = 0.4
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The real question lies in the last part of the code. How do I call ContentView's function to change the background color?

```
if self.draggedOffset.width <= -120 {
    // Call the ContentView's changeBackGround function and pass in Color.red
    print("background should change to red")
}
if self.draggedOffset.width >= 120 {
    // Call the ContentView's changeBackGround function and pass in Color.green
    print("background should change to green")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `SwipeBar` to take a `Binding` to a `Color`:

```
struct SwipeBar: View {
    @Binding var color: Color
    ...
```

and then update the value of `color` where appropriate in `SwipeBar`:

```
.onEnded { value in
    if self.draggedOffset.width <= -120 { self.color = .red }
    else if self.draggedOffset.width >= 120 { self.color = .green }
    ...
}
```

In `ContentView`, create a `Binding` to the `backGroundColor` property and pass it to `SwipeBar`:

```
SwipeBar(color: self.$backGroundColor)
```